# how to retrieve entities from already exist azure table storage

Tags: c#, azure

Here is my code

```
 string storageConnectionString = AppSettings.LoadAppSettings().StorageConnectionString;

        // Retrieve storage account information from connection string.
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = DOTFORMS3.Common.CreateStorageAccountFromConnectionString(storageConnectionString);

        CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

        CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("Doctors");

         TableQuery<CustomerEntity> tableQuery = new TableQuery<CustomerEntity>();
        foreach (CustomerEntity CustomerEntity in table.ExecuteQuery(tableQuery))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Customer PartionKey : {0}", CustomerEntity.PartitionKey);
            Console.WriteLine("Customer RowKey : {0}", CustomerEntity.RowKey);
            Console.WriteLine("Customer Name : {0}", CustomerEntity.NAME);
            Console.WriteLine("Customer Place : {0}", CustomerEntity.PLACE);
            Console.WriteLine("Customer Time : {0}", CustomerEntity.TIME);
            Console.WriteLine("Customer Phonenumber : {0}", CustomerEntity.PHONENUMBER);
            Console.WriteLine("Customer Email : {0}", CustomerEntity.EMAIL);
            Console.WriteLine("******************************");
        }
```

here is my customer entity class

```
 public class CustomerEntity : TableEntity 
{    
            public CustomerEntity()
    {


    }

    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string EMAIL { get; set; }
    public string PHONENUMBER { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public string PLACE { get; set; }
    public string PRICE { get; set; }
    public string TIME { get; set; }
}
```

here is what it displays

[image]
here is my azure storgae table

[image]

so why it does only display partition and row key and not the other proprties ?
and what if i want to display other properties that are not defined in my customer class how to do it ? thx :)

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code for your CustomerEntity model. I guess I am ready for another kiss from you ;-).

Comment: alright i made it , i hope u get it as u always do xD

Comment: I am able to run your code without any problems. Can you share (I mean the tool) where are you seeing this data (2nd screenshot of table)?

Comment: i made another table and deleted old one and it just worked fine , i dont know what was wrong actually , maybe it is some azure tech stuff , literally  all i did was create another tabel

Comment: I noticed in your `CustomerEntity` that you have fields like `Email` and `EMAIL`. Could it be possible that you started with fields in camel case (Email) entered the data and then added fields in uppercase (EMAIL). Please note that attribute names in a table are case sensitive and the tool you used to view the data is converting the attribute names in the grid to upper case. That would explain why you're not seeing the data.

Comment: i am pretty sure i did check that out and i am pretty sure its azure fault lol xD 
thx again for ur time

Comment: it would be rly great if u could answer this question , [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62624156/how-to-create-a-microsoft-azure-mobile-application], thx :)