# How to create a Microsoft Azure Mobile Application

Tags: .net, azure

i can't find the Create `Mobile app` any where on my subscription to azure all i can make is `web application` and here are some photos of what i see
[Web App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mq9up.jpg)

and here is another photo of what services i can make [my Subscription Services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9rwD.jpg)

every tutorial i found speaks of making a `Mobile App` but i cant seem to find that option on my Account , Am i missing something?

Comment: Have you referred to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-windows-store-dotnet-get-started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because of, is still a web application is just about configuration, you need to do this:

1. Create the web application
2. Deploy your app
3. Once deployed, go  to  `Deployment details`
   and click on the Resource of Type `Microsoft.Web/sites`.
4. Click on the Configuration blade under Settings and in the
   Application settings, click on the New application setting button.
5. In the Add/Edit application setting page, enter Name as
   `MobileAppsManagement_EXTENSION_VERSION` and Value as latest and hit
   OK.

Extracted from the official documentation here:
[Create Android application in azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/previous-versions/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-get-started)

You can also get the iOS, Cordova, Xamarin and some other documents in the same link.